# Large textinput makes http post fail

Tags: html, forms

I have a form in my application where technicians input information about different events or actions taken (like updating a server). The problem is that these inputs can be quite lengthy and then my form stops working. The server returns a 302 error to the browser if the browsers tries to send data, but just as often the browser does nothing when I try to submit. When the browser does nothing a quick look in the Chrome Developer Tools shows that the browser tries to execute a post to the correct path, but the status is listed as failed. This always occurs if the textarea contains more than ~3500 characters. I've tried to change the enctype to see what happens but it hasn't solved the problem.

```
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="/some/path/" method="post" _lpchecked="1">
<fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" name="machineId" value="some_integer">
    <input type="hidden" name="eventId" value="some_integer">
    Titel:
    <select name="form[title]">
        <option>Some_option</option>
        <option>some_option</option>
    </select>

    <textarea name="form[text]" rows="25" cols="90"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Spara" title="Spara">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Any ideas on why it doesn't work and what can be done?

EDIT:
My application is based on PHP and running on Debian/Apache. I haven't been able to find any settings that might prevent the post from working correctly. I do have a post_max_size set at 8MB, but a text of 3500 chars are not larger than 8MB so...

Comment: By chance, does your server have a max post size? May be hitting the max post site threshold, which causes it to bounce. (Also, try using `multipart/form-data` as the form `enctype` and see if there is any change (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is the default value of `enctype`)

Comment: I haven't been able to find any settings in my server that might have this effect, but if you can give me and hint on what to look for I'll check again. I'm running Debian/Apache. I've also tried a few different enctypes but they all give the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text via `POST` will most likely NOT be 1 byte/character. Apache mod_security might be filtering the data. And it could be any other number of Apache mods that affect post encryption. You might check out [mb_get_info()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-get-info.php) and other mb_* functions to verify how PHP is encoding the text.  If you don't want to have to dig too deeply, you can make an educated guess from a couple data points as to how many bytes per character are being used in your POST and adjust `post_max_size` to suit your needs.

If you are cannot print errors to screen, you can check out

`tail -n 30 /var/log/apache2/error.log #prints last 30 lines of error.log`

immediately after your white screen symptom to get more detailed information on errors/warnings/etc encountered during the script.

Also note that `post_max_size` is limited by `memory_limit` ... I don't think that is the issue, but it may be something to consider for another reader.

Comment: In the apache log I found that it is an "Segmentation fault". Doesn't really solve my problem since they are hard as h*ll to track down, but you gave me the answer so kudos for you.

Answer (score 0):

what server side language you are using? maybe you need some text compression like this one [Huffman Algorithm](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/computersciencetheory/huffman.html)

Comment: Sorry, totally missed that info. I'm running PHP 5.2.6