# What is _lpchecked="1" for in a form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm starting to do some web development and I was learning about forms and bumped into this field: `_lpchecked = "1"`.

I found examples of form with this field in this StackOverflow question
[Large textinput makes http post fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591885/large-textinput-makes-http-post-fail) or in [this example page](http://thecodemine.org/examples/example_13_nested_routes.html) of the jQuery Formwizard plugin

Comment: It doesn't have a special meaning in HTML. It seems Wordpress-related, after a quick Google. Don't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks.. If you add an answer with this info I could mark it as answered

Comment: It's not Wordpress related

Answer (score 182, accepted):

This attribute is added by the LastPass browser extension, to store the fact that LastPass has checked that form for login fields.

It's not something that the page author would have consciously added to the page, it's down to the extensions that the user *viewing* the page has chosen to use.